# IIS8 http to https redirect stuck in a loop

Tags: redirect, iis, https

I have used so many forums and officiall IIS, ASP.Net an Microsoft Website examples on how to enable a simple http to https redirect on IIS8.5 but all I get no matter what is a loop error.

I have a site with a binding for http://subdomain.domain.com on a set IP address and port 80, and another binding on the same site in IIS to https://subdomain.domain.com on a set IP to 443

I then have this rule setup using the URL Rewrite module on the site web.config.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
            <rule name="http to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
</rewrite>
```

If I try and hit the http version of the site, it appears to redirect, but ends up getting caught in a loop and failing.

What am I doing wrong? There are no other redirects handled by the code. Do I need to provide more info?

Comment: We have the same rule on our ISS, but with other reason (See other 303) and that rule works on our server. can't see that we have stop processing checked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, after all it seems that the culprit is our web application firewall and how it manages forwards to DMZ servers.

Comment: Would be useful if you described what you did with the firewall.